# $_POST better writing quality

Tags: php, post

I have this code :

```
if(isset($_POST['prenom2'])){
    $t['prenom2'] = $_POST['prenom2'];
}else{
    $t['prenom2'] = '';
}

if(isset($_POST['nom2'])){
    $t['nom2'] = $_POST['nom2'];
}else{
    $t['nom2'] = '';
}

if(isset($_POST['prenom3'])){
    $t['prenom3'] = $_POST['prenom3'];
}else{
    $t['prenom3'] = '';
}
```

etc (there are 5 or 6 fields I need to test).

There must be a better way of doing this, like if a given index of POST isn't set, that index is...

Thanks

Comment: You could do a `foreach()` loop.

Comment: `$t['prenom2'] = isset($_POST['prenom2']) ? $_POST['prenom2'] : '';`? using a ternary operation, each `if()` could be done in 1 line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your real problem, you may choose one of these:

```
 for($i=1; $i<6; $i++){
     $t['prenom'.$i] = (isset($_POST['prenom'.$i])) ? $_POST['prenom'.$i] : '';
     $t['nom'.$i] = (isset($_POST['nom'.$i])) ? $_POST['nom'.$i] : ''; 
 }
```

or

```
 $indexes = array('prenom2'=>'', 'nom2'=>'', ...);
 $t = array_merge($indexes,$_POST);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use foreach.

```
$indexes = array('prenom2', 'nom2', ...);
$t = array();

foreach ($indexes as $i) {
    $t[$i] = isset($_POST[$i]) ? $_POST[$i] : '';
}

print_r($t);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `if..else..` condition then you can use ternary `:` operator as

```
$t['prenom2'] = (isset($_POST['prenom2'])) ? $_POST['prenom2'] : '';
$t['nom2'] = (isset($_POST['nom2'])) ? $_POST['nom2'] : '';
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically the same as the answer from Matei but moved in a function to reduce duplicate code.
Parameter `$t` is your final array and `$key` is a string representing the array index. The final `$t` array is also returned so there is no need for passing a reference.

```
function setT($t, $key)
{
  $t[$key] = isset($_POST[$key]) ? $_POST[$key] : '';
  return $t;
}

$t = setT($t, 'prenom1');
$t = setT($t, 'prenom2');
$t = setT($t, 'prenom3');
```